# AWS SQS and visibility timeout during an exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Im curious to know, is the visibility timeout respected if an exception is thrown by the app after taking a message off the sqs qeue..

Im of the impression it is respected, so if an exception is thrown in the application say validation failed, the message remains on queue before being moved to the DLQ? ie until  timeout elapses.

is that correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "exception is thrown on SQS" and "an exception is thrown in the app"? Is this an error in the Amazon SQS service, or in your own application? Can you provide an example with a bit more detail?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i mean in the application.. say the message has incorrect values or format of a numeric field. An exception is thrown as i want the message to move into the DLQ. I was initally under the impression this would happen staright away, not after a timeout. We for instance have large timeout. ideally dont want a message hanging around for a minute until timeout elapses before being moved, is that correct?

Comment: Why don't you want it "hanging around for a minute until timeout elapses before being moved"? Is there something you would do to the message once it is in the Dead Letter Queue that requires this fast response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your application calls `ReceiveMessage()`, a message is returned and that message is made 'invisible' in the queue. When your application has finished processing the message, it should call `DeleteMessage()` to remove the message from the queue.

If that is not done within the *invisibility timeout* period, then **the message will 'reappear' on the queue so that it can be re-processed**. This means that if your application throws an exception and does not complete processing the message, then the message will be re-processed.

However, if this happens multiple times, then the message will be **moved to the Dead Letter Queue**. This prevents a situation where the message continually fails to be processed. When configuring the SQS Queue, you can configure the number of retries before sending the message to the Dead Letter Queue.

Amazon SQS requires the timeout because that's how it knows that processing has failed. It **has no insight into the actual application failure** -- it can only assume it since the timeout period has passed. For a 'quicker' response, you can use a very small timeout period, and then have your application send a 'heartbeat' signal to SQS at frequent intervals, telling it that the message is still being processed, and therefore resetting the invisibility timeout period.

Comment: I appreciate the answer.